# Allocate memory and store metadata

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

Let's say, i want to allocate a block of memory and store some metadata infront of that block.
To do that, i came up with this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct metadata_s{
    char someMetaData[3];
}metadata_t;

typedef struct mem_block_s{
    metadata_t metadata;
    //Insert padding so 'data' has fundamental alignment
    char padding[sizeof(max_align_t) == sizeof(metadata_t) ? 0 : sizeof(max_align_t) - (sizeof(metadata_t)) % sizeof(max_align_t)];
    char data[];
}mem_block_t;

void* allocateMemory(size_t size){
    mem_block_t* newMemBlock = malloc(sizeof(mem_block_t) + size);
    if(newMemBlock != NULL){
        return(newMemBlock->data);
    }
    return(NULL);
}

int main(void){
    double* doubleArray = allocateMemory(100 * sizeof(double));
    if(doubleArray != NULL){
        doubleArray[0] = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

There are multiple issues with this:

- C only guarantees no padding at the start of a struct, there may be additional padding inside the `mem_block_s` struct
- Ultimately, i return and assign a pointer to a `char` array to (in this case) a `double` pointer (am i allowed to do that?)

Instead, i could do something like

```
typedef struct mem_block_s{
    metadata_t metadata;
    void* data;
}mem_block_t;
```

and allocate memory for `data` seperately, but then just given the `data` pointer, i will have a hard time accessing the metadata.

What would be the proper C way to do something like this?

Comment: Get rid of the padding member and change the `data` member to `char _Alignas(max_align_t) data[];`. That both simplifies the code and solves the problem of the compiler hypothetically inserting unnecessary padding.

Comment: Re “(am i allowed to do that?)”: Yes and no. Arguably, you create an effective type for the memory by writing to it as a `double`, but the standard is not written in a formal way that makes this completely clear. I expect it not to be a problem with current compilers. (Also yes because the C standard prohibits very little; you are **allowed** to do it. Your question should actually be whether the behavior is defined.)

Comment: Thanks, i forgot about _Alignas. That simplifies things.

Answer (score 1):

As a devoted gcc user I would use zero union with zero sized arrays.

```
typedef struct metadata_s{
    char someMetaData[3];
}metadata_t;

typedef union
{
    char c[0];
    unsigned char uc[0];
     /* ... */
     double dbl[0];
}DATA_t;

typedef struct mem_block_s{
    metadata_t metadata;
    //Insert padding so 'data' has fundamental alignment

    DATA_t data[];
}mem_block_t;

void* allocateMemory(size_t size){
    mem_block_t* newMemBlock = malloc(sizeof(mem_block_t) + size);
    if(newMemBlock != NULL){
        return(newMemBlock->data);
    }
    return(NULL);
}

int main(void){
    DATA_t* doubleArray = allocateMemory(100 * sizeof(double));
    if(doubleArray != NULL){
        doubleArray -> dbl[0] = 1.0f;
    }
}
```

But I know that is not very portable - probably it will not work using

Comment: That's something, but i kind of wanted to avoid gcc extensions and have something that just returns a pointer thats compatible with one that malloc would return.